# Add double quotes each n lines and remove existing line breaks

Tags: macos, csv, text, sed

I have a Mac and want to create a CSV and separate rows by double quotes each 5 rows and then remove existing line breaks in each row.

For example, I want to convert the following text:

```
My
Name
is
Michael
I'm
25
Years
Old
```

To the following text:

```
"My Name is Michael"
"I'm 25 Years Old"
```

Can this be done using Numbers, TextEdit, any online tool, any free software, SED commands or just any tool?

Thanks

Comment: You have divided your text by each 4 row, not 5.

Answer (score 0):

This won't win any golf contests, but:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n/"$1 $2 $3 $4"\n/g' input-file
```

There's certainly a cleaner way to do this, but this is at least more general:

```
perl -wle 'while(!eof){ undef $a; 
    $a .= <> for(1..4); $a =~ s/\n/ /g; 
    chop $a; print "\"$a\""}' input
```

Comment: Hey William :) Thanks very much for this! Can I modify it to be every 50 lines instead of 5 lines? 5 lines was just for demo

Comment: this works well but if there are 4 or less lines remaining, they will not be included at all in the output

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` - on the 4th line the concatenated string `s` is printed.

```
awk 'BEGIN {n=0;s=""} 
    {
      if (s=="") s=$0; # first field should not have leading space
      else s=s " " $0;

      if (!(++n % 4))  # after 4 lines print concatenated string
      { 
         printf("\"%s\"\n" , s); s="";} 
      }' textfile
```

Comment: this works well but if there are 4 or less lines remaining, they will not be included at all in the output

Answer (score 0):

Here is an short `awk`

```
awk 'NR%4==1 {printf "\""} {ORS=NR%4?" ":"\""RS} 1' file
"My Name is Michael"
"I'm 25 Years Old"
```